# more than one slideToggle in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have a simple code with slideToggle function that is working fine in 4 divs, it opens hidden content all at the same time in this Divs.

It changes the image when clicked, but only the first one, not the rest, how can i do it for all?

this is the code for the 4 buttons repeats equaly, it opens all, but wont change image in all:

`<div class="show" style="display:none"><h1>THE TEXT TO APPEAR</h1></div>
<a href="#"><img id="bg" class="loadMore" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/masGris.svg" /></a>`

`$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.loadMore').click(function() {
        $('.show').slideToggle('1100');
        var src = $("#bg").attr('src') == "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/less.svg" ? "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/masGris.svg" : "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/less.svg";
        $("#bg").attr('src', src);
        return false;
    });
});`

Comment: Please provide a little code fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$("#bg")` of selector with `$(this)` .because id is unique one.for all image try with `each()`

**updated**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.loadMore').click(function() {
        $('.show').slideToggle('1100');
    $('.loadMore').each(function(){  
var src = $(this).attr('src') == "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/less.svg" ? "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/masGris.svg" : "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/less.svg";
        $(this).attr('src', src);
        })
        return false;
      });
    });
```

Comment: This only changes the icon that i clicked in. What about to change it all, no matther with one i click?

Answer (score 0):

This only changes the icon that i clicked in. What about to change it all images, no matther with one i click? someone?